# What is this error: ERC-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate corresponding Transfer Event Logs), Check with Sender

Tags: web3py, erc20

https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x76e440006690c02f87d110c3389e8738e56fcbcd454a29cf24154bfee4d49576

Why is this transaction failing?

Edit 1: web3 py code

```
contract_address = "0x07865c6E87B9F70255377e024ace6630C1Eaa37F"
contract = web3.eth.contract(contract_address, abi=token_abi)

print(f"My balance: {contract.functions.balanceOf(my_account.address).call()}")
print(f"Receiver balance: {contract.functions.balanceOf(receiver_address).call()}")

raw_txn = {
    "from": my_account.address,
    "gasPrice": web3.eth.gasPrice,
    "gas": 200000,
    "to": contract_address,
    "value": 0,
    "data": contract.encodeABI('transfer', args=(receiver_address, 1234567)),
    "nonce": web3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_account.address)
}



signed_txn = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(raw_txn, PRIVATE_KEY)
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)enter code here
```

EDIT 2: I changed it to use the contract transfer function now it works. I don't know the reason

```
value = 100000
contract_call = contract.functions.transfer(receiver_address, value)
unsigned_txn = contract_call.buildTransaction({'chainId': web3.eth.chainId, 
'from':  my_account.address,
"nonce": web3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_account.address),
'gasPrice': web3.eth.gasPrice})
signed_txn = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(unsigned_txn, PRIVATE_KEY)

# signed_txn = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(raw_txn, PRIVATE_KEY)
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)

signed_txn.hash 
web3.toHex(web3.keccak(signed_txn.rawTransaction))

#waits for transaction to complete
tx_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(signed_txn.hash)
tx_receipt['status']


print(f"My balance: {contract.functions.balanceOf(my_account.address).call()}")
print(f"Receiver balance: {contract.functions.balanceOf(receiver_address).call()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The transaction has a non-zero ETH `value`.

The proxy contract redirects it correctly to the [implementation contract](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xe27658a36ca8a59fe5cc76a14bde34a51e587ab4#code). But the implementation's `transfer()` function does not use the `payable` modifier, so it's not able to accept ETH value. Which fails the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added my python code piece, what am I doing wrong

Comment: @adam Your python code correctly sets the `value` as 0, but the linked transaction has a non-zero `value`. Does the same issue occur with all the same params, except the`value` is set to zero?

Comment: chnaged from raw transaction to contract function. Value wasn't making a difference with raw_transaction

Comment: potentially with raw_txn method data needs to change, at least that is my guess

Comment: @adam The implementation contract does not implement the `fallback()` nor `receive()` function, so it does make a difference whether the `data` field is empty / contains an existing function selector / contains an unrecognized selector. Combined with the fact that the `transfer()` function is not `payable`, the `value` property of the transaction also makes a difference... Because the transaction was accepted by the network, there's no issue with signing nor broadcasting, just with the values of properties of the transaction object.